# Is Datalog negation and the built-in predicate $ \neq $ similar?

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra, fixed-point, datalog

I was reading "Principles of Database & Knowledge-Base Systems, Vol. 1" by Jeffrey D. Ullman. There is a chapter about Datalog negation and as I was seeing the problems of negation I kept thinking that using the predicate $ \neq $ would solve those problems but then I see the following:

p(X) :- r(X) & ¬q(X).

q(X) :- r(X) & ¬p(X).

The problem is this has 2 minimal models and if I'm not mistaken so does this:

p(X) :- r(X) & q(Y) & X $ \neq $ Y.

q(X) :- r(X) & p(Y) & X $ \neq $ Y.

Is there an equivalence between these 2 operators? If so, did I miss it or is it not mentioned that it's unsafe to use $ \neq $ with recursion?

Comment: Doesn't choosing $p,q$ to be the empty set satisfy the second clause set? I would expect that to be the least fixed point.

Comment: I've answered your same q on lambda-the-ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a misunderstanding in regards to the evaluation algorithm/minimal model.

The derivation of new values is atomic e.g.:

step 1:

- **p** = {}
- **q** = {}

step 2:

- **p** = **r**
- **q** = **r**

In step 2 **p** and **q** only see the value that each other had at step 1(the old value). I thought **p** and **q** would have access to the value of the current step and thus, the order of evaluation would produce different results.

To answer the question:

p(X) :- r(X) & q(Y) & X ≠ Y.

q(X) :- r(X) & p(Y) & X ≠ Y.

only has one minimal model: **p** = **r** and **q** = **r**.